# Add html elements and json list inside angular typescript class

Tags: html, angular, typescript, list, tags

I have this code.

```
  this._notificationService.showInfoMessage
        (
          'The list below cannot be reached'
            + `'<ul>
             <li> ${this.tagList
            .map(i => i.tag)
            .join(',')} </li>
            </ul>'`
        );
```

It does not work

I want add html list **inside component.ts** file for this tag list and show list items one by one as a list with bullets.
I have tried many ways.

I made it using browser inspect view
I want to get as below one

[image]

please suggest best way for this

Comment: using `[innerHTML]` could be way to go, but its not recommended. Can you please share whats going on inside `showInfoMessage` method? Perhpas combination of `{{}}` interpolation and `*ngFor` can make this work.

Comment: @PankajParkar
Its only for notification to ui. can pass string value as a param.  something like string message

Comment: I want to add this on .ts class file

Comment: @Max, Its not a good practice to pass HTML that you would directly append to DOM. I would suggest that you refactor NotificationService & pass it a template reference

Answer (score 0):

Why it doesn't work?
Just check what says the official Angular documentation.

> Angular recognizes the value as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it,
> which removes the script element but keeps safe content such as the
>  element.

https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example

That is how it's working!

But still, you have many options to achieve your goal.

Since you have a list/array of tags you could just iterate over them in the template and use string interpolation.

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{tag}}</li>
 </ul>
```

Text interpolation:
https://angular.io/guide/interpolation

P.S Please, share with us what your service/component looks like.